# How to change the led on this board to a brighter led? 12v input

Tags: led, circuit-design, soldering, surface-mount

[image]

Needed to change these led to brighter led. Is it possible?

If yes then how can it be done?

Noobie!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is almost certainly possible. I'm not sure exactly which part you are asking about.

One way of looking at it is that the brightness of the LEDs will depend mostly on two things:

1. The efficiency of the LED (in converting electrical power to light).
2. The power consumed by the LED.

So, you could just replace your LEDs with more efficient ones (without changing anything else in the circuit) and you should get more brightness.

Alternatively, you could change (reduce) the value of a couple of resistors to increase the current flowing through the LEDs. Power = Current x Voltage, and the voltage across an LED is roughly constant, so more current means more power.

For best results, you may need to combine both of these ideas. (Buy some good quality bright LEDs and refer to their data sheet to choose best resistor values).

The big word of warning with both approaches is that you should not allow so much current to flow through the LED as to destroy it. You should check the datasheet of your LED to find this limit (or, if you have no datasheet and lots of LEDs, then test one to destruction to find how much current is too much, then use a bit less than that).